# Suspend QR code detection while dialog is shown

Tags: android, qr-code, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to create a real time QR Code decoder which allows user to confirm/cancel data read from the camera view.
(Of course, according confirmation or cancelation, it will execute some code...)

But there's a bad point:
The app I coded keeps reading qr code data even while in dialog and I can't find a way to prevent it.

Here is my main activity:

```
public class MainReadActivity extends Activity {


private SurfaceView cameraView;
private TextView barcodeInfo;
private BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
private CameraSource cameraSource;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_read);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);


    cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);

    cameraView.requestFocus();
    barcodeInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.code_info);

    barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE).build();


    cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector).build();


    cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {


            try {
                cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                Log.e("CAMERA SOURCE", ie.getMessage());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            cameraSource.stop();
        }
    });


    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {
        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

            if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                barcodeInfo.post(new Runnable() {    // Use the post method of the TextView
                    public void run() {

                        ConfirmationDialogFragment myDialog = new ConfirmationDialogFragment();
                        myDialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"");
                        barcodeInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        barcodeInfo.setText(barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });



}
```

And here is my DialogFragment:

```
public class ConfirmationDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {



public Dialog ConfirmationDialogFragment(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_confirmation,null);
    builder.setView(v);


    Dialog dialog = builder.create();

    return dialog;
}
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Bests,
P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop and start camera on barcodeDetector callback

```
barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {
        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

            if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                cameraSource.stop();
                barcodeInfo.post(new Runnable() {    // Use the post method of the TextView
                    public void run() {

                        builder
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to reset the count?")
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {    

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());

                    }
                })

                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Did Reset!", 5).show();

                    }
                })
                .create();
                        barcodeInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        barcodeInfo.setText(barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @André!
 the cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder()) fixed my problem! Thanks, keep rocking.

Comment: I found that calling `cameraSource.stop()` caused the BarcodeDetector Processor to stop processing the rest of the code in the `receiveDetections` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forget some like this.

```
builder.setPositiveButton(Ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss(); //this close the dialog.
        }

    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(Back, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ///do another thing
        }
    });
```

I hope this help you

Comment: You're right. But unfortunately didn't fixed the problem.
Please, take a look at my public {void receiveDetections} which implements a runnable (UPDATED)...

Answer (score 0):

just call the **Camera.release()** method after detection

```
@Override
 public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections < TextBlock > detections) {
  final SparseArray < TextBlock > items = detections.getDetectedItems();
  if (items.size() != 0) {

   mTextView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
      TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
      stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
      stringBuilder.append("\n");
     }
     mTextView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
     mCameraSource.release();

    }
   });
  }
 }
```